# Как указать координаты объекта в юнити 2d

Tags: unity3d

В коде приведённом ниже, нужно указать координаты GameObject Player как это сделать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float openable_distance = 3f;
    private bool isOpened = false;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    private float dist;

    [SerializeField] private Sprite OpenedGate, ClosedGate;
   


    private void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, СЮДА НУЖНО КООРДИНАТЫ ИГРОКА.transform.position);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && dist <= openable_distance)
                {
            if (isOpened == false)
            {
                rend.sprite = OpenedGate;
                coll.enabled = false;
                isOpened = true;
                
            }
            else
            {
                rend.sprite = ClosedGate;
                coll.enabled = true;
                isOpened = false;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: А зачем вы убрали 2 собственные правки в вернулись к первому непонятнмоу варианту?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно обратиться к свойству `position` класса Transform твоего объекта и указать его в качестве параметра

```
private Transform _playerTransform = default;

private void Start()
{
    _playerTransform = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _playerTransform.position);
}
```

---

Либо закешировать объект через редактор и потом также указать

```
[SerializeField]
private Transform _someObjectTransform = default;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _someObjectTransform.position);
}
```

А вообще в `Update()` инициализировать новую переменную типа Vector3 и потом еще брать различные значения объектов очень дорого по ресурсам. Вынеси в отдельный метод и вызывай его

Comment: Vector3 dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _someObjectTransform.position);

Comment: @ТигрСерж спасибо за информативный комментарий